# Converting functional component to class component

Tags: reactjs

I have one functional component, but as I need to use now state and more complex logic, I would like to convert it to class component. 
But I don't know exactly how to get it working:

My functional component:

```
  import React from 'react';

  const FileList = (props) => {
    const items = props.items.map((item) => {
      return <p key={item.reqId} > { item.name }</ p>
    });

    return <div>{items}</div>
  }
```

And I tried to do that:

```
  export default class FileL extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
    }

    render() {
      const { items } = this.props;
      items = props.items.map((item) => {
        return <p key={item.reqId} > {item.name}</ p>
      });
      return (
        <div>{items}</div>
      );
    }
  }
```

But this is not working.It says "items" is read-only.
I would like to keep the same functionality.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your render function

```
render() {
      const { items } = this.props;
      items = props.items.map((item) => {
        return <p key={item.reqId} > {item.name}</ p>
      });
      return (
        <div>{items}</div>
      );
    }
```

`items` is `const` so you can't override it. This has nothing to do with React. And you shouldn't reassign a props element, even if its defined with `let`. You might use the following:

```
render() {
      const { items } = this.props;

      return (
        <div>
        {
          items.map((item) => <p key={item.reqId} > {item.name}</ p>)
        }
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
export default class FileL extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          {
             this.props.items.map((item) => {
                 return <p key={item.reqId} > {item.name}</ p>
             })
          }
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Actually you don't need to convert your component to class based component, as React 16.8 comes with [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). Using `Hooks` you can do whatever you can do with class based component. They let you use state and other React features without writing a class.